# Get request for url with [ ] in it

Tags: php

I need to get the value of a parameter in the URL which isn't set by me and out of my control. It is a drop down menu with various options, yes, no, maybe.

It looks like this:

```
<select name="abc_filter[2z51292c01075]">
 <option>Yes</option>
 <option>No</option>
 <option>Maybe</option>
</select>
```

I tried `echo $_GET['abc_filter[2z51292c01075]']` but the result is always empty/nothing instead of either yes, no or maybe depending on what is selected.

Comment: You probably meant this `$_GET['abc_filter']` if you echo that parameter it will give you this numbers 2z51292c01075! For better answer put full url in question and tell us which parameter you want to get.

Comment: No, in the html that is the name property of the select menu `<select name="abc_filter[2z51292c01075]">`

Comment: *I need to get the value of a parameter in the URL* your question is not clear.

Comment: I have updated my question, does it help?

Comment: Likely you should have put `2z51292c01075` as a `value` on one of the options. With this set up you'll need to iterate over `abc_filter` and get the key. Maybe https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php unless you have 2+ of these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `var_dump($_GET['abc_filter']);` you'll get something like `array(1) { ["2z51292c01075"]=> string(2) "Yes" }`. `$_GET['abc_filter']` is an array, so you can use

`$_GET['abc_filter']['2z51292c01075']`

to access the value with key 2z51292c01075.